# WPF: Populate a listbox on window load

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

How can it be done with c#?

I'm able to populate a listbox on a button click, but don't know how it can be done on application startup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the same code in the constructor of the form.

Comment: That was so simply! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alex: If it helped.  Don't forget to mark as answer to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Double click on the form (empty space).

This will generate a Window_Loaded(...) {}; event.

Put your code between the curly braces.